# GAE : com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL : Error Code 404

Tags: google-app-engine

Hi I have created a java application using maven build. I can successfully deploy it to my local app engine but while deploying it on cloud I am facing errors . Error is below:

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=recro-test&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'recro-test').

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=recro-test&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'recro-test').

Kindly suggest some solution.﻿

Comment: I have also created an application on appengine cloud and have mentioned that application name in my application-web.xml

Comment: From the information you have supplied, you seem to be attempting to upload to an application called `recro-test`.  This application already seems to be [live](http://recro-test.appspot.com).  Seems like you managed to resolve the problem.

Comment: You may want to add an answer to this question on why this error occurred and how you solved it.  That way people who encounter this error in the future and brought to the StackOverflow site will be able to learn from your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not an issue rather it was a mistake that I was committing and figured out that I was deploying the project on app engine by right clicking the project --> google--> Deploy to App Engine. Following this path I was getting error as it was not GAE project.

It was successfully deployed using Google App Engine WTP as my project was a dynamic web project.